# Alamofire not getting full response

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to fetch data from a `GET` request using Alamofire in Swift. There's an issue where it's not getting the full response from the request. The response is an array with nested arrays some `String` and some `[String:Any]`. I've none of the `[String:Any]` gets pulled in using Alamofire and think this is a serious bug. Postman shows the nested array values but not Alamofire.

**The request**

```
Alamofire.request(request.getFullUrl(param: paramsForUrl), method: request.getMethodType(), parameters: data, encoding: request.getEncoding(), headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<500).responseJSON { response in }
```

**What a typical response should look like**

```
{
  "uuid": "787FDS8-FS7FS7DG9-FSD789FCS98",
  "name": "Show time",
  "views_count": 0,
  "comments_count": 0,
  ...
  "events": [
    {
      "uuid": "f69a358e-9a1e-427c-a158-95dfc8c54ed7",
      "name": "Test",
     ...
    },
    {
      "uuid": "8993b639-f6c9-4d20-b8a9-c43c73a9828b",
      "name": "Test 2",
      ...
    },
   ...
  ]
  "times: [
   {
   "name: "test time 1",
   "clock: "Face"
   },
   {
   "name": "test time 2",
   "clock: "Back"
   }

 ]
}
```

**What's missing**

Anything inside nested arrays: `events, times`. If I have a simple array of `String` then Alamofire gets these. It doesn't show anything nested and this is with both printing `response.result.value` and JSON decoding the response and accessing `events` directly. It doesn't see `events` or `times`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From your question if alamofire gets the array of string, then may be issue with the structure of the json with nested values.

Comment: You should post what you're actually seeing from the data returned by Alamofire, as a string.

Answer (score 0):

May be your JSON is not valid. To check that try changing `responseJSON` to `responseString` and see if it prints all the data e.g.

```
Alamofire.request(url ,method: .get ,parameters: data).validate().responseString{ response in
    switch response.result{
        case .success:
            let s = response.result.value ?? "nil"
            print("API Response: \(s)")
        case .failure:
            debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

If the above is printing all the data from your server than you need to fix the service

Answer (score 0):

Delete **.validate(statusCode: 200..<500)** and try again.

```
  Alamofire.request(url ,method: .get ,parameters: parameter).responseJSON{ response in
       switch response.result{
       case .success:
           let value = response.result.value ?? "nil"
           print("API Response: \(value)")
       case .failure:
           print("error")
        }
    }
```